# Emailing people their details (e.g. flight numbers or in this case colour)

Tags: excel, email

[image: a simple example]

How would you go about sending each person their favourite dance and colour in Columns B and C to each person (Column A) in each row to their respective email address? (Column D)

This would be useful because for a large conference, you might have 100+ delegates all with individual flight information. It's not so much a mail merge as an email merge.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Comment: @Ralph agreed. I think this is a question that fits better on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), and have flagged it for migration there.